# How to get the date of record updating in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table that one of this record has been changed.

Is there any MySQL function to get the date of this updating?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. There is no way to get that modification date unless you explicitly stored it somewhere else (through a trigger or application side technique).

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on how you are using the data value.

but mostly it is a good practice to have both created_at and updated_at as attributes for your table.

OR if you want to keep each update date info for a record then store them in different table. before each update in main table insert existing row in tracking table from main table.

Comment: Thank you,but the change happend and I want to know when It happend.I will do what you said for the feature changes.

Comment: yes need to store date time of change in trackchanges table or updated_at column in main table.