# mySQL Select DISTINCT ips based on dates and return dates

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing this query to know the count of unique IPs by date.
The fact is that I need to return in PHP not only the number of unique IPs by date, but also the dates itself.
How can I do it?

```
function getTotUniqueVisitsDay($id) {
    $query="SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_ip) FROM campaigns_visitors WHERE campaign_id = ".$id." group by date";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Getting tot unique visits by day failed: " . mysql_error());   
    $visits_by_day = mysql_num_rows($result);
    return $visits_by_day;   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_ip)
FROM campaigns_visitors
WHERE campaign_id = ?
GROUP BY date
```

This doesn't return `date` as you have found.

You should have more luck with

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_ip), date
FROM campaigns_visitors
WHERE campaign_id = ?
GROUP BY date
```

Others are likely to recomment that you use prepared statements and `mysqli` routines; I have helpfully translated your query to a format that can be prepared.

I trust you can construct the PHP to manipulate the changed statement.

Answer (score 0):

The best practise is to store the date as last_updated and date_created column. This post suggest how to get update date for any table 
[How can I tell when a MySQL table was last updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307438/how-can-i-tell-when-a-mysql-table-was-last-updated)

and according to following post you can't get update date for specific row in a table
[How to get the date of record updating in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044889/how-to-get-the-date-of-record-updating-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

```
function getTotUniqueVisitsDay($id) {
    $query="SELECT date_field FROM campaigns_visitors WHERE campaign_id = ".$id." group by date_field";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Getting tot unique visits by day failed: " . mysql_error());   
    $visits_by_day = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $visits_by_day['count'] = count($visits_by_day);
    return $visits_by_day;   
}
```